# Imprimir objetos mediante un arreglo o for

Tags: java, array, imprimir

ahi esta como tengo los objetos pero no se como imprimir cada uno en un mismo arreglo :( y que se recorran de forma automática por cada objeto.

No se como hacer un arreglo o for para recorrer un método imprimir para cada objeto, y me muestre los resultado de cada uno sin necesidad de mandarlo a imprimir directemente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código de la Clase triangulo, por favor evita agregar código en imagenes

Comment: gracias por el consejo, es mi primer post. en un momento pego el código

Answer (score 0):

Crear una lista para guardar objetos de tipo Triangulo:

```
List<Triangulo> lista = new ArrayList<>();
```

Agregar los objetos a la lista:

```
lista.add(new Triangulo("Triagulo 1",1,2));
lista.add(new Triangulo("Triagulo 2",1,2));
lista.add(new Triangulo("Triagulo 3",1,2));
```

Recorrer la lista con un for:

```
for( Triangulo t : lista){
    t.imprimir();
}
```